# Store pointers to variables in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, pointers

I have a number of classes, each of which has a number of variables of type `Date`. e.g.

```
class MyClass1 {
    var dt1: Date
    var dt2: Date
    var dt3: Date
}
class MyClass2 {
    var dt1: Date
    var dt2: Date
    var dt3: Date
}
```

I want to make a list that contains references to dates in instances of either class. e.g. It might contain a reference to dt1 in an instance of MyClass1 and another to dt2 in an instance of MyClass2. I will use this list to set those dates to a specific value.

I can see how I might do this by storing the class instances with a flag indicating the date referred to (e.g. using an enum). I could then use a switch to determine which date to set. However, is there a more Swifty way to do this? What I ideally want to do is treat each date variable as an object that I can add to the list and then set to a different value.

I'll also need to do this for some numeric variables, so need an approach that will work for both.

Comment: This sounds like a strange design. How are you planning to use this construct? Maybe we can find better alternatives

Comment: Can you add an example of usage?

Comment: Here is some more information on the application. I have a number of classes representing financial objects such as employment, pension, annuity, savings etc. These are independent and (rightly) don't know about each other. However, the user might wish to link, for example, employment end date (retirement) with pension start date. My app then allows these now-linked dates to be changed and models the effect on income.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to treat `Date` (which is a `struct`) as a reference type (i.e. a `class`). There's an easy way to accomplish this with a wrapper class:

```
class DateRef {
    let date: Date

    init(_ date: Date) {
        self.date = date
    }
}

class MyClass1 {
    var dt1: DateRef
    var dt2: DateRef
    var dt3: DateRef

    init(dt1: Date, dt2: Date, dt3: Date) {
        self.dt1 = DateRef(dt1)
        self.dt2 = DateRef(dt2)
        self.dt3 = DateRef(dt3)
    }
}

// same for MyClass2 ...

let m1 = MyClass1(dt1: Date(), dt2: Date(), dt3: Date())
let m2 = MyClass2(dt1: Date(), dt2: Date(), dt3: Date())

var dates = [m1.dt2, m2.dt1]
```

Comment: But `Date` is already a `struct` referencing an object - i.e. `NSDate`. Why going the other way around?

Comment: Thanks. This is just what I need. It has clarified that I need my dates to be mutable objects.